# Getting 401 Unauthorized error when threads in JMeter increase

Tags: jmeter, unauthorized

I am running a JMeter script, where I get the Access Token which I use it for my HTTP Request Samplers (By using Bearer ${AccessToken} in Header Manager of each Request). My HTTP Requests are being categorized into multiple Simple Controllers.

There are 70 HTTP GET Requests and ONE Thread takes around 20 seconds to execute them all.

Now when my no. of threads increase, say 3 onwards, then I start getting 401 Errors

```
({
    "statusCode": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Bad token",
    "attributes": {
        "error": "Bad token"
    }
})
```

for a few requests. But eventually 401 errors start getting high as no. of Threads increase, keeping Ramp Up time low. for eg: for 5 Requests Ramp Up time = 30 sec.

[JMeter Script snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlEfn.png)

I have checked, my Access Token call always return a different token which is used per new THREAD. so not sure where the issue is :(
So far I have not used any think times, maybe that is one of the issue, but not sure.

Comment: 401 is coming from the server, so did you check server side to see why is it not accepting authentication?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your http get response , The issue is caused most likely due to incorrect value of `AccessToken`.

Make sure you are passing correct `AccessToken` to get response.

IF you have a recorded script log, check where this access token originating from and make sure your [regular expression extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) is extracting it correctly.

For more information on extracting variables and reusing it in the script you can read this [article.](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)